# Given a point $P$ and a hyperplane $H$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ such that $P \in H$, there is $T$ linear such that $T(P)=(0:\cdots:0:1)$ and $H:X_0=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

> Show that given a point $P$ and a hyperplane $H \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $P \in H$, there is a linear transformation $T$ such that $T(P)=(0:\cdots:0:1)$ and $H$ is given by the equation $X_0=0$.

A hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$ has equation $a_0X_0+\cdots+a_nX_n=0$.

Let $P=(b_0:\cdots:b_n)$.

Since $P \in H$, $a_0b_0+\cdots+a_nb_n=0$.

How can I proceed? Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go up one dimension and into affine space. There $P$ corresponds to the line $L = (tb_0, tb_1,\ldots,tb_n)$ and $H$ still has the same equation.

Now apply a linear transformation to $\Bbb A^{n+1}$ that moves $H$ to be orthogonal to $(1, 0,0,\ldots,0)$ (remember that $H$ originally is orthogonal to $(a_0, \ldots,a_n)$) (this might move $L$ to someplace else). Then apply another linear transformation that fixes $(1, 0,\ldots,0)$, but rotates the (new) $L$ to the line $(0,0,\ldots,0,s)$. Lastly, project back down to $\Bbb P^n$.

I don't know that this gives you the neatest description of the transformation, but it is, at least in my opinion, the most straight-forward way to prove that it is *possible* to do it.

Comment: @Leafar The first transformation to move $H$ into plase might move the line $t\cdot (b_0.\ldots,b_n)$ to some other line. What you want to do for the second transformation is to find one that doesn't move $H$ (that is, keeps the orthogonal vector fixed), but moves this new representative of $P$ to where you want it (along the last coordinate axis).

Comment: So an example of such transformation, given by its matrix, is the product $T_2 T_1$ where $T_1$ is the matrix of the transformation that moves $H$ to be orthogonal to $(1,0,\ldots,0)$ and $T_2$ is the other transformation. I think I understand which are the possible matrices $T_1$. Can you give some example of $T_2$?

Comment: @Leafar you want it to fix $(1,0,\ldots,0)$, so the top left element of the matrix must be $1$, and the rest of the first column must be $0$. Also, since no vector of $H$ should be moved out of $H$, the rest of the top row must also be $0$. Now we restrict ourselves to $H$ and consider it as a copy of $\Bbb A^n$ . Within there, you have a vector (the new directional vector of $L$, without the first $0$) that you want to move to $(0,0,\ldots,1)$, so find an invertible matrix that does that. That matrix will fit right in the remaining $n\times n$ minor matrix of $T_2$.